# How do I get Member permission for Search-companies Details in #Linkedin API using PHP?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'm trying to search company from my #LinkedIn Profile using Keywords to get searched company details like (Website Url, Headquarters, Industry, Type, Company Size, Founded etc...). But API is showing Error **Member does not have permission to get company info**. I'm using PHP programming for this.

I have used API Library (Version 3.3.0 of the Simple-LinkedIn library) from website " https://code.google.com/archive/p/simple-linkedinphp/downloads "

I have searched 'Retail' company after configuring above library in our server. I think there is issue in Oauth2.0 configuration of #LinkedIn API because above mentioned Library is having Oauth 1.0 method, which very old and it is not supporting. I am getting 403 Forbidden error.

Please provide me following information :-

1. Is it there any latest LinkedIn API available for ***Search-Company*** details using latest Oauth2.0 method ? If any Please do share the #LinkedIn API Library of latest Oauth 2.0 method.
2. Is it search company details from LinkedIn API free or Paid? If it is Paid one, May I know the procedure and Cost of it along with limitation of its use ?